# Are S3 storage costs based on total current usage or on total volume ingested

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose I have a script which uploads a 100GB object every day to my S3 bucket. This same script will delete any file older than 1 week from the bucket. How much will I be charged at the end of the month?

Let's use pricing from the `us-west-2` region. Suppose this is a 30-day month and I start with no data in the bucket at the beginning of the month.

1. If charged for maximum bucket volume per month, I would have 700GB at the end of the month and be charged $0.023 * 7 * 100 = $16.10. Also some money for my PUT requests ($0.005 per 1,000 requests so effectively 0).
2. If charged for total amount of data that had transited through the bucket over the course of that month, I would be charged $0.023 * 30 * 100 = $69. (again +effectively $0 for PUT requests)

I'm not clear on which of these two cases Amazon bills. This becomes very important for me, since I expect to have a high amount of churn in my bucket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your calculations are incorrect, although the first one comes close to the right answer, for the wrong reason.  It is neither peak nor end-of-month that matters.

The charge for storage is calculated **hourly**.  For all practical purposes, this is the same as saying that you are billed for your *average* storage over the course of a month -- not your maximum, and not the amount you uploaded.

Storing 30 GB for 30 days or storing 900 GB for 1 day would cost the same amount, $0.69.

> The volume of storage billed in a month is based on the average storage used throughout the month. This includes all object data and metadata stored in buckets that you created under your AWS account. We measure your storage usage in “TimedStorage-ByteHrs,” which are added up at the end of the month to generate your monthly charges.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#billing

This is true for `STANDARD` storage.

`STANDARD_IA` and `GLACIER` are also billed hourly, but there is a notable penalty for early deletion:  Each *object* stored in these classes has a minimum billable lifetime of 30 days in IA or 90 days in Glacier, no matter when you delete it.  Both of these alternate storage classes are only appropriate for data you do not intend to delete soon or retrieve often, by design.

`REDUCED_REDUNDANCY` storage follows the same rules as `STANDARD` (hourly billing, no early delete penalty) but after the most recent round of price decreases, it is now only less expensive than `STANDARD` in regions with higher costs.  It is an older offering that is no longer competitively priced in regions where `STANDARD` pricing is lowest.

Comment: Where did you find this info? I couldn't find any references to hourly accounting on the S3 billing page.

Comment: This was information I already knew, so I didn't actually look it up in the docs, though I should have so that you'd have a reference.  Updated the answer with a citation from from the S3 FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Your bill will for storage will be closer to your #1 example, perhaps a bit higher because for brief amounts of time, while uploading the 8th day, you still have 7 days of storage accruing charges, but you won't be charged anywhere near your #2 example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need a script to delete files older than 1 week. You can set a transition cycle on the bucket which will automatically do that; or might be transfer contents to Glacier ( with 10% cost ) if you might need them later.

Secondly, storage cost might not be huge.. Probably better idea would be to that script first deletes data from S3 ( if u want script to do that ) and then you add more data.. so that your bucket overall never have more data and you are always charged on consistent storage basis.

Thirdly, your main charges could be bandwidth charges (if not handled well) which can be really huge  as you are transferring so much data. If all this data is generated internally from your grid then make sure u create VPC endpoint to your S3 so that you don't pay "bandwidth charges" as then this data transfer will be considered to be transferred on intranet.